# next number in which last set bit is same

Tags: bit-manipulation

Let's take a number `2(0010)` I want another number in which last bit set should be same as in 2 which is at first position(k=1)

According to the rule we first use the formula `x&-x` to extract the last set bit of any number and add it to the original number

But here in this case last set bit is same as the number and we if we apply the formula in this case the we will get `4(0100)` on adding `0010` and `0010`
but we should get `6(0110)`

Comment: "According to the rule" - What rule are you referring to?

Comment: just use `(x&-x)<<1`? if the last set bit should not change, than do not touch it.

Comment: Are you always check cking the number 2 or is this your example case. If so, then what are you exactly wants, explain this with another example.